# Как делать join для нескольких таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Раньше имел минимальный контакт с `join` и прошу подсказать как сделать такой запрос или сменить архитектуру.

есть таблица `regions`

```
id, name
1,  Москва    
2,  Санкт-Петербург    
3,  Саратов
```

таблица `cities`

```
id, parentid, name
10, 1,        Реутов
11, 2,        Шушары
12, 3,        Энгельс
```

и, соответственно, таблица с моими данными `data`

```
id, location, name    
1,  1,        Иван
2,  3,        Степан
3,  11,       Петр
```

Как сделать так чтобы можно было сделать выбор из таблицы `data` с подстановкой локации из обоих таблиц `regions` и `cities`?
Т.е. На выходе получить

```
1, Москва,          Иван
2, Санкт-Петербург, Степан
3, Шушары,          Петр
```

заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: подумайте насчет изменения структуры бд, если это конечно возможно. несовсем понятно что есть localtion, почему не **CitiId** почему с cities ParentId не RegionId? было бы более прозрачно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы сделал как то так

```sql
SELECT
  data.id,
  regions.name,
  city.name
FROM data
JOIN regions
  ON data.regionId = regions.id
JOIN city
  ON data.cityId = city.id
```

P.S.: я бы поля в Data именовал как то так RegionId, CityId откуда понятно что есть что

UPD:

в первоначальном примере если бы city и regions были не соединены между собой, в Вашем же случае это будет выглядеть так

```sql
SELECT
  data.id,
  regions.name,
  city.name
FROM data
JOIN city
  ON data.location = city.id
JOIN regions
  ON city.ParentId= regions.Id
```

Answer (score -4):

Я бы на Вашем месте переделал организацию хранения данных, потому что выглядит как очень пагубная практика, когда приходится ассоциировать данные из третьей таблицы с таблицей второй, а та, в свою очередь, ассоциирует это всё с первой.

Comment: Почему пагубная? Если обе связи будут по индексам, то будет точное попадаение в строку. Иногда бывает запрос по десятку таблиц и отрабатывает моментально.

Comment: Совершенно нормальная нормализованная БД с суррогатными ключами. Это использовать денормализованные БД без причины - пагубная практика.